# Why didn't Visual Studio warm me about a logical comparison error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was dumb and forgot, when making logical comparisons in a portion of my code in Visual Studio to use "==" instead of "=". My program compiled and ran fine, which interested me. Visual Studio seems to catch a lot of errors like syntax, but I'm wondering now why it didn't catch my error in compilation or even before compiling. I've seen other IDEs catch these logical errors before and during compilation.

Is this a compiler issue? Or an IDE specific issue?

I'm just curious.

Comment: Unless you paste the code, no one can help.

Comment: instead of x == y, I had x = y. Does that help? I explained it in my post, if you even bothered to read.

Comment: It depends on the context. Inside an if () it does warn.

Comment: @user10150308 - Here on Stackoverflow, which you've just joined, we've been roiled by debate on how welcoming to be to newcomers who don't know how to post proper questions, even though there are a million examples on the site.  And now, here, you show with your comment exactly why it's a wasted one-sided effort.  "If you even bothered to read."  Huh.

Comment: @davidbak And now, here, you show why most people hate on stackoverflow. Because of elitists like you who can't afford to take 1 minute out of your day to answer a question you may have have answered before. Sorry to take such precious time out of your life to make you post on a question you could have simply ignored. Must be a fun time. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assignment in condition is allowed by C++ standard but if you consider it misleading then enable the warning. It is Visual Studio warning [C4706](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4706). Simplest way to enable it is to set compiler warning level to 4.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ both assignments and comparisons are just expressions like any other. There's no specific "logic condition expression" or "assignment expression". It's all just expressions.

That's the reason you can have *any* kind of expressions in a conditions, not only "boolean" or "conditional" expressions. Here follows a *few* examples of expressions that are valid in conditions: `1`, `0`, `someFunctionReturningADoubleValue()`, `someFunctionReturningAnObjectWithIntegerConversionOperator()`, `"foo bar"`, `'h'`.

In C++, all expressions resulting in a non-zero value are considered "true", only the value "zero" (integer `0`, floating point `0.0` (exactly!), `false`) is "false".

And the result of an assignment expression is the value being assigned. So the result of `a = 0` is `0` (if `a` is e.g. an `int`) which is false, and `s = "hello world"` is `"hello world"` (if `s` is a `char const*`) which is true.

This is the reason you might see some code with the operands of a comparison being the other way around, e.g. `0 == a` instead of `a == 0`. That will help catch such logical errors as you now have, because `0 = a` is not correct and will cause a compiler error, whereas `a = 0` might not.

Comment: @user10150308 Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: If `s` is a `char const *`, then the assignment `s = "hello world"` does not give the value `"hello world"`.   The resultant value is the address of the first character in the string literal (i.e. the address of the `char` that has value `'h'`).  That address is non-zero, so its value tests as true.